# What is the purpose of using useRef(uuid())?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, uuid, reconciliation

Recently I've found pretty strange and new to me way of using useRef.
useRef(uuid()) - is it a valid way of generating stable id, or something that is should rather be avoided?

Comment: you use useRef when state management is not required. see another example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will generate a stable id, but in it's current form it will call `uuid()` each and every render cycle. Here it's likely not a big deal, but imagine instead if it was a heavy function. Calling it each render cycle could effect performance. Instead you might consider using a `useEffect` hook to assign the  ref value.

Example:

```
const idRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  idRef.current = uuid();
}, []);
```

You could also create a getter function that returns the current ref value and only creates it when necessary.

Example:

```
const idRef = useRef();

const getId = () => {
  if (!idRef.current) {
    idRef.current = uuid();
  }
  return idRef.current;
};
```

See [How to Create Expensive Objects Lazily](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily)